# In Java, do primitive types and arrays have a containing package?

Tags: java, arrays, package, primitive-types

In Java, do primitive types and arrays have a containing package?

Probably not, but just want to be certain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Simple Answer

Let's test:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    System.out.println(long.class.getPackage());
    System.out.println(Object[].class.getPackage());
}
```

Output:

> null
>   null

No they don't :-)

---

### Primitive Types

Primitive classes are special constructs that don't have a package. For reference, see the source of [`Long.TYPE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#TYPE), the alias for `long.class`:

```
/**
 * The <code>Class</code> instance representing the primitive type
 * <code>long</code>.
 *
 * @since   JDK1.1
 */
public static final Class<Long> TYPE =
       (Class<Long>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("long");
```

As you can see, a primitive class is loaded through a package-private and native mechanism:

```
static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);
```

and casted to `Class<Long>` (in order to enable auto-boxing, I guess)

### Wrapper Types and their Primitive Types

BTW: every wrapper class has a static final field called `TYPE` that maps to the corresponding primitive class, as the following code shows:

```
private static Class<?> getPrimitiveClass(final Class<?> wrapperClass){
    try{
        final Field field = wrapperClass.getDeclaredField("TYPE");
        final int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
        if(Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)
            && Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)
            && Class.class.equals(field.getType())){
            return (Class<?>) field.get(null);
        } else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is not a wrapper class: "
                + wrapperClass);
        }
    } catch(final NoSuchFieldException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is not a wrapper class:"
            + wrapperClass + ", field TYPE doesn't exists.", e);
    } catch(final IllegalAccessException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is not a wrapper class:"
            + wrapperClass + ", field TYPE can't be accessed.", e);
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args){
    final List<Class<?>> wrappers =
        Arrays.<Class<?>> asList(
            Byte.class, Long.class, Integer.class,
            Short.class, Boolean.class, Double.class
            // etc.
        );
    for(final Class<?> clazz : wrappers){
        System.out.println("Wrapper type: " + clazz.getName()
            + ", primitive type: "
            + getPrimitiveClass(clazz).getCanonicalName());
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> Wrapper type: java.lang.Byte, primitive type: byte
>   Wrapper type: java.lang.Long, primitive type: long
>   Wrapper type: java.lang.Integer, primitive type: int
>   Wrapper type: java.lang.Short, primitive type: short
>   Wrapper type: java.lang.Boolean, primitive type: boolean
>   Wrapper type: java.lang.Double, primitive type: double

---

### Array Types

Arrays can be created through [`Array.newInstance(type, length)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class%2C%20int%29), which internally calls this method:

```
private static native Object newArray(Class componentType, int length)
throws NegativeArraySizeException;
```

so again, the classes are special constructs created by native code (and they don't have a package, or else you could find them somewhere)

Comment: `System.out.print(long.class);` outputs `long` , does that mean long is class ?

Answer (score 4):

**No** they don't have,as they aren't class.

**Primitive**  : A primitive type is predefined by the language and is named by a reserved keyword.

**array** : An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.

Comment: `Object[]` might be a class, as you can use it as a type argument.

Comment: @John @fin can you give an example , I am not following you .

Comment: If you have a generic interface `interface InterA<F> { }`, you can call it with an array as the parameterizing type (e.g. `InterA<Object[]>`). Not sure if this proves that `Object[]` is a class, though.

Comment: @finnw no, `Object[].class` is a class. `new Object[0]` is an Object

Comment: @John Assymptoth: no, in this case it's a type parameter, but not a class

Comment: @John as parameter it accept reference type, I mean anything that can be referenced.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd, I mean `Object[]` is a class, in the same way that `Object` is a class.   I think you mean `Object[].class` is a `Class<Object[]>`

Comment: @finnw but Object is not a class, it's a type. Object.class is a class.

Comment: @finnw I'm not. a `Class` is an `Object`, a class isn't :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, but there are objects to wrap primitive data types in the `java.lang` package.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

No since they are language constructs and not classes per-se.

You can however have a class representing a primitive type in the wrapper for instance:

[Integer.TYPE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) et al. useful for reflection.

But you'll see that still those don't have a package ie.

```
Integer.TYPE.getPackage()
```

Returns null