# Where are the Default primitives defined in C++, c and java?

Tags: java, c++, c

In java, by default it includes java.lang.* [does this have the primitives] It includes Boolean,Integer,... Wrappers so that compiler can understand our definition when we say Integer i.

How about primitive data types?

How is it known?

Where's it defined?

How does the compiler know how much memory to be alloted?

```
int x;
double d;
```

how it know int is 4 [2 bytes] , double is 8 bytes?

sizeof gives the size accordingly. is it like metadata available to compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737311/in-java-do-primitive-types-and-arrays-have-a-containing-package

Comment: It is related in compiler

Comment: For Java, the primitives are part of the language, defined in the language specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Mats Petersson's answer:

```
How does the compiler know how much memory to be alloted?
```

The memory to allocate depends on the platform.  The size of each fundamental type has a guaranteed minimum range.  The amount of memory is at least that size.

For example, an unsigned char has the range 0 to 255, which is 8 bits.  The compiler must allocate a minimum of 8 bits; but it can allocate 12, 16 or 32.

In general, the size of an `unsigned int` is the native word size of the platform, *as long as the processors word size can support the minimal range specified by the standard.*

There is no guarantee than an `int` is 4 bytes or a `double` to be 8 bytes.  Some floating point processors support more than 80 bits.

```
Where's it defined?
```

The range specifications are stated in the C++ language standard and the compiler's definitions are stored in system file `<limits>` or `<climits>`.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, these primitives are just that: primitives. They are defined in the compiler itself (ok, in a "portable" compiler, where the compiler has compile options for different architectures, one suspects that there are multiple files defining these types). The C standard (and the same applies to C++) defines some minimum sizes for these types, but the actual size is up to the compiler.

Most likely, these types aren't THAT special, it's just that some code during initialization sets up the types and defines the size, alignment requirements, and other basic criteria for these types. And of course, how to generate code to access and do the required built-in operators, on these types.

And yes, `sizeof()` is resolved by using the data about the type during compilation. For compound types (`struct`, `class`, `union` and arrays), the compiler will also take into account alignments in the size.